# Enterprise Edition Controller events not firing if Full Page Cache is enabled

Tags: magento

So on one of our recent launches we had a lot of events that we were observer such as controller_action_predispatch. Once the site went live we started noticing that our observers were never getting called for those. After a little investigation one of our developers found this block of code in Mage_Core_Model_App around line 292

```
if ($this->_cache->processRequest()) {
            $this->getResponse()->sendResponse();
        } else {
            $this->_initModules();
            $this->loadAreaPart(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_GLOBAL, Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::PART_EVENTS);

            if ($this->_config->isLocalConfigLoaded()) {
                $this->_initCurrentStore($scopeCode, $scopeType);
                $this->_initRequest();
                Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates();
            }

            $this->getFrontController()->dispatch();
        }
```

As you can see if $this->_cache->processRequest() that is true which it is when full page cache is enabled you never get to the dispatch. The developer did find http_response_send_before which gets call either way but it seems to me like this is a bug or you should never ever use those controller dispatch events for anything if you have full page caching enabled. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the nature of the full page caching, I'd call this "works as intended". While it can be a little strange not to have some events firing, they had to pick a line and this one makes sense to me, especially since the controller is never really dispatched.

You should use those controller dispatch events for anything that affects the page (as it still needs to be generated), but if you are using it for tracking and such, no it would not be appropriate.

Comment: I see what you are saying, obviously if they have the cache and can display the page then don't go through the whole dispatch path. We were using it for parameters in the url. Looks like we will just use that other one. Do you know if this will be true for the cart page and checkout pages. I have another project where I doing something with controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index and it would suck to have to find a different way. I am removing something from the session

Comment: It's trivially testable, but I would go ahead and guess that it doesn't dispatch that event either.

Comment: yeah I just tested and it makes sense that they wouldn't full page cache the cart and it doesn't appear that the do. It got to my event everytime. Obviously you can't cache the cart and checkout because of the data that gets put in for each user and changes

Comment: Depending on the version full page caching is only for "non-session visitors". Having items in your cart implies a session.

Answer (score 4):

See here if you want to learn how Caching works with Magento Enterprise

http://magentophp.blogspot.com/2011/02/magento-enterprise-full-page-caching.html

Answer (score 1):

The only reliable event to listen for **with and without Full Page Cache enabled** is `http_response_send_before`.

Comment: I did see that http_response_send_before was dispatched, but if you look at dispatchEvent method in Mage_Core_Model_App, $this->_events is actually empty when full page cache is hit so it doesn't run the whole dispatch stuff at all

Answer (score 0):

**`controller_front_send_response_before`**

This event will be fired irrespective of FPC enabled