# What's the earliest event Magento dispatches?

Tags: magento

I need to fire off an event, as early as possible in the dispatch process, when a customer visits a frontend controller.  The request is to be analysed and will, potentially, be redirected to a different URL, justifying the "as early as possible" requirement.

What's the earliest event a developer can subscribe to?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The earliest event I'd rely on is

```
controller_front_init_before
```

The Magento front controller object (distinct from the the "index.php front controller") is the object that managers the routers, which in turn manages the **action** controller dispatch.

There's a few others (`resource_get_tablename`, `core_collection_abstract_load_before`, `core_collection_abstract_load_after`) that fire before, but they're more of the side effect variety (Magento using it's own systems to bootstrap itself) than anything you'd want to rely on.

Finally, as should always be pointed out, if you do a little logging in `app/Mage.php`

```
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
{
    file_put_contents('/tmp/events.log',"$name \n",FILE_APPEND);
    Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
    #$result = self::registry('events')->dispatch($name, $data);
    Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    return $result;
}
```

patterns begin to emerge.

Comment: I presume the routing layer is unaffected by {full page,block} level caching?  I don't have access to an enterprise installation, otherwise I'd test full page myself.

Comment: @Nick I wouldn't make that assumption. When FPC (or Lightspeed or similar) is enabled, the Mage controller never gets hit, therefore never throwing an Event.  Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4735354/336905 - I can help with access to a EE testbed if you need.  Block caching is different since the Controller still gets called.

Comment: @Nick: A mage coming out of the full page cache won't fire that event.  Full page cache happens up in the core/app model's run method, before any routing is done.

Comment: @Nick -@Alan Storm gave you a good hint - FPC in Magento EE is run as much close to the start as possible - to skip all the loading and initing Magento does. The only event, that is fired in the most cached case, is `http_response_send_before`.

Comment: Alan also wrote a "magento quickie" about this: http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/32402056167/magento-startup-events -- Thanks Alan!

Comment: Mind that the event `controller_front_init_before` only works when configured under the `global` node.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for `controller_action_predispatch` event.

There are a bunch of other events fired before it, but in this case I am assuming you still want to access the dispatched action controller.

If you want it even earlier, then your best bet would be `controller_front_init_before`, which is fired before the front controller is initialized.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of events in Magento [1.4.1.1](http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento_events_cheat_sheet/1_4_1_1.html) and [1.5.1.0](http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento_events_cheat_sheet/)

There is also an event for each of the controller_action_predispatch and controller_action_postdispatch. To know which actions are being called you can add the following line

```
Mage::log('controller_action_predispatch_'.$this->getFullActionName());
```

to the `preDispatch` function of `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php`

A similar line can be added to `postDispatch` function in the same file.

Comment: Answered with the aid of the OP's blog post.  Why is there no badge for that? :)

Comment: My bad. Didn't do enough research on the OP only the question ;), but the second part of the answer is not from any of your blog post.

Answer (score 2):

After some sluething it seems that - in terms of **Magento EE Full Page Cache** being enabled - the only **reliable** event you can listen for is `http_response_send_before`.